# Adding Attribute to XML node C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

I am trying to add an attribute to XML node

Actual Value

```
<Hardships>
<Hardship IsPrimary="true" EstimatedHardshipDuration="MEDIUM" HardshipReason="UNEMP" IsSeekingEmployment="Y" IsResolveableIn3MonthsVerbal="N" />
</Hardships>
```

Expected after node Change

```
<Hardships>
<Hardship IsPrimary="true" EstimatedHardshipDuration="MEDIUM" HardshipReason="UNEMP" IsSeekingEmployment="Y" IsResolveableIn3MonthsVerbal="N" HardshipEndDate="11/21/2017 12:00:00 AM/>
</Hardships>
```

I wrote code like this

```
var requestDocument = new XmlDocument();
requestDocument.LoadXml(requestString);
var todayDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
var hardShipEndDate = todayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK");
var HardshipDudeNode = requestDocument.SelectSingleNode(HardshipWorkoutOptionsRequestNodeXml);
//adding an attribute to XML node
HardshipDudeNode.Attributes.Append(requestDocument.CreateAttribute("HardshipEndDate", hardShipEndDate));
```

I am getting an output like this

```
<Hardships>
 <Hardship IsPrimary="true" EstimatedHardshipDuration="MEDIUM" HardshipReason="UNEMP" IsSeekingEmployment="Y" IsResolveableIn3MonthsVerbal="N" IsResolveableIn6MonthsDocumented="Y" p7:HardshipEndDate=""
xmlns:p7="2017-11-21T00:00:00.0000000-05:00" />
</Hardships>
```

why i am getting the attribute like his "p7:HardshipEndDate=""
xmlns:p7="2017-11-21T00:00:00.0000000-05:00" ? can someone help me out.

Comment: The is no reason your formatting should not work.  Try declaring the string as a string instead of var : string hardShipEndDate = todayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because first argument here is element name and second is namespace:

```
requestDocument.CreateAttribute("HardshipEndDate", hardShipEndDate)
```

And you don't set value anywhere. Instead do it like this:

```
var hardShipEndDate = todayDate.ToString("G");
var endDateAttr = requestDocument.CreateAttribute("HardshipEndDate");
endDateAttr.Value = hardShipEndDate;
HardshipDudeNode.Attributes.Append(endDateAttr);
```

Note that such datetime format is unusual for xml. If you are not required to produce dates in that specific format, better use

```
// or XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local
var hardShipEndDate = XmlConvert.ToString(todayDate, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the format you set, is not what you want it to be.
According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) all you need to change is:

```
var hardShipEndDate = todayDate.ToString("G");
```

Comment: Still, I am getting like this



`<Hardship xmlns:p7="11/21/2017 12:00:00 AM" p7:HardshipEndDate="" IsResolveableIn6MonthsDocumented="Y" IsResolveableIn3MonthsVerbal="N" IsSeekingEmployment="Y" HardshipReason="UNEMP" EstimatedHardshipDuration="MEDIUM" IsPrimary="true"/>`